# Excel Convert Row to Matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

**Is there an integrated function of Excel 2016 to transform a series of 1x95 lines of data into unique 5x19 matrices?**

I have a ton of 5x19 matrices that are getting imported into Excel.  Unfortunately, due to the way that they exported/imported, this results in a ton of 1x95 lines.

Since the number of matrices will be unknown, I'm working on writing a macro to handle this, but I'm having issues.  I've got the new row insertion working well, but I'm struggling to recursively cut the correct regions and paste to the correct regions.  If there is already a built in feature to excel which would allow me to select a line and transform it into a 5x19, that would save me a ton of time.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post screenshots of what the data looks like when you first import it and a mockup of what you want it to look like.

Comment: If you change o Excel 2021 or Excel 365, you can use the SEQUENCE function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Structure 95x1:

One approach that should do the trick with Excel 2016 is using the `OFFSET` function as follows:

```
=OFFSET($A$1:$A$95,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$1)+((ROW()-ROW($B$1))*(ROWS($A$1:$A$95)/5)),0,1,1)
```

In newer versions of Excel, you could use the following simple approach:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,SEQUENCE(5,19))
```

Botch approaches assume that your data is stored in column A and that you know the size of the matrix in advance (5x19). However, if necessary, you can do this dyanmically.

---

**EDIT:** Data Structure 1x95:

For this data structure you need to adjust the formula as follows (this assumes that your data is stored in the range `A1:CQ1` and your matrix starts in cell `A3`; which of course can be changed according to your needs):

```
=OFFSET($A$1:$CQ$1,0,COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$3)+(ROW()-ROW($A$3))*(COLUMNS($A$1:$CQ$1)/5),1,1)
```

For the `INDEX` function you would simply need to change the corresponding array.

Comment: That sounds pretty close to what I want.  So, my data is stored in n rows of length 95, not n columns of length 95.  If I just swap each instance of "column" with "row" and vice versa, would it format the rows?